# Unable to read image by using imshow

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I am new to OpenCV I was trying to read image in visual studio 2012 but was not able to load image using `imshow` but it works fine when I use `cvLoadImage`.

When I execute the following code it works fine but

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//char key;
int main()
{
    IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("test1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    cvNamedWindow("hah", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    cvShowImage("hah", image);
    waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}`
```

but when I write the following code it throws an exception and image does not renders

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
//char key;
int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("test1.jpg");
    namedWindow("My");
    imshow("My", image);
    waitKey(50000);
    return 1;
}
```

I am not able to understand what is the problem.

Comment: That is because you are not using the function correctly. Please refer to [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread) for details.

Comment: Your code sample looks fine to me. You may be getting error because you are trying to display an empty image. Make sure that the image is read from file and not empty. You can check for empty image with `if (image.empty()) { cout << image.empty() << endl;} else {imshow("My", image); }`.

Comment: I've been having same issue on Windows. My work around at that time was to avoid using imread. Your code works fine for me on Linux.

Comment: Try using full path like "D:/Test/test1.jpg" instead of just "test1.jpg".

Comment: @Alex image is not empty since it works fine for cvreadImage.

Comment: @scap3y can you please tell whats wrong with syntax

Comment: Syntax looks fine to me... are both samples from the same project? So no difference in relative pathes or something?

Comment: @Micka ya relative paths are same

Comment: @user3285373 I suggested checking for empy image as a first step to debugging the problem. If the image is empty then you know that the problem is with `imread` function. So was the image empty?

Comment: @Alex no man image arent empty since the cvShowImage works fine